# how to pass multidimensional array (having numeric keys ) from controller to template?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, templates

My controller code is as below,

```
$errorData = array(1) {
                        ["val_0"]=>
                                  array(2) {
                                          ["created_at"]=>
                                           string(0) ""
                                          ["user_email"]=>
                                          string(29) "email address cannot be empty"
                                  }
              }
```

there may be val_1, val_2.... etc.

I just want to pass this array `$errorData` to template and print it in foreach loop.
How can I do that. I am not able to get what variable to be called in template to access those messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, pass data array as below:

```
$data["error"] = $errorData;
$this->load->view("VIEW_FILE",$data);
```

In view, your `$data` extracted. so you will get your error array as $error

```
foreach($error as $e) // val_0, val_1....
{
   //$e is now having val_0 at first loop run
   echo $e["created_at"];
   echo $e["user_email"];
}
```